# a problem with @click.option while passing "prompt" and "type" together

Tags: python

I pass both "prompt=True" and "type=(str, str)" together as @click.option and it's fine while I'm using the option but when I want to use the prompt feature - if I don't provide the parameter - then as expected it would ask for the parameter by defining a prompt string. the problem is it counts any character as an input value.

for example:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--replace",
    "-r",
    help="for replacement write the phrase you want to be replaced and then write the substitutional phrase",
    type=(str, str),
    prompt=True
)
def main(replace):
    click.echo(f"you want to replace {replace[0]} with {replace[1]}")
    
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the result in the command line would be:

```
>>> python app.py
>>> Replace: str1 str2
Error: 2 values are required, but 9 were given.
>>> Replace:
```

I want to pass two string values. first is "str1" and the second is "str2" which raises an error. Is there any specific character that I have to use for declaration and separation? or it's a problem with the library itself?

Also, I ran the code on both Windows and Linux.

```
full specs:
  os: windows 10
  python: 3.10.6
  click: 8.0.3 & 8.1.7

  os: linux
  python: 3.10.11
  click: 8.1.7
```